# How do I access a web page from Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I want to run this PHP script  `http://db2express/imacs/radek/3.1/rationalTest.php?mode=create` from Sinatra. Sinatra runs on a different box.

Is there any Sinatra built-in way how to do that?

I know I can use `mechanize`, just wondering if there is something else to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Open-URI`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/) will do a good job if all you need to do is retrieve the content of the URL or tickle some job at the other end of the URL.

If you need more control then [`Net::HTTP`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html) or [`Typhoeus`](https://github.com/pauldix/typhoeus) are available.

Both Open-URI and Net::HTTP are part of Ruby's standard installation.

> I just want to add further that "HTTParty" is a very good wrapper around "Net::HTTP" (see httparty.rubyforge.org)

Yes, I agree. It's nicely done. I reach for OpenURI first since it's built-in. HTTParty is lighter-weight than Typhoeus so it's nicely positioned between them.

Comment: Greg is right, but I just want to add further that "HTTParty" is a very good wrapper around "Net::HTTP" (see http://httparty.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: one more question: Can I restream the output to the web browser?

Comment: That is up to you. Once you have captured the body of whatever is sent you can parse it, "repurpose it", store it, or send it.

Comment: Yes, you can though I doubt you'll gain much. Both Open-URI and Net::HTTP let you pass a block that will be called as the content is read. See the first example in Open-URI's docs, and `Net::HTTPResponse#read_body`. The reason I don't think you'll gain much is your restreaming will be throttled by the speed of the data coming into you.