# Creating a single page proxy using Ruby Sinatra

Tags: ruby, proxy, sinatra

I am trying to use Ruby Sinatra to create a simple proxy for a specific web page. I can do it in C#, I just can't seem to work it out for Sinatra, the C# code is below:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Map" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public class Map : IHttpHandler {

static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
    int read;
    while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
}

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string gmapUri = string.Format("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap{0}", context.Request.Url.Query);
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(gmapUri);

    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = response.ContentType;
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        CopyStream(responseStream, context.Response.OutputStream);
    }
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

The Ruby Sinatra code I have tried is as follows:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/mapsproxy/staticmap' do
  request.path_info = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap'
  pass
end
```

I am assuming that the Sinatra one does not work (get a 404) as is is only passing the request to pages in the same domain. Any hep would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

With **the Tin Man**'s help I've come up with a nice succinct solution, which works well for me:

```
get '/proxy/path' do
   URI.parse(<URI> + request.query_string.gsub("|", "%7C")).read
end
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 4):

If you want your Sinatra app to retrieve the URL, you'll need to fire up a HTTP client of some sort:

```
get '/mapsproxy/staticmap' do
  require 'open-uri'
  open('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap').read
end
```

I think this will work and is about as minimal as you can get.

You could use [HTTPClient](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient) if you need more tweakability.

Also, I think that Rack can do it. Sinatra is built on top of Rack, but it's been a while since I played at that level.

> I still need to find a way to extract the contentType from the response

From the [Open-URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/) docs:

```
The opened file has several methods for meta information as follows since
it is extended by OpenURI::Meta.

open("http://www.ruby-lang.org/en") {|f|
    f.each_line {|line| p line}
    p f.base_uri         # <URI::HTTP:0x40e6ef2 URL:http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/>
    p f.content_type     # "text/html"
    p f.charset          # "iso-8859-1"
    p f.content_encoding # []
    p f.last_modified    # Thu Dec 05 02:45:02 UTC 2002
}
```

For your purposes something like this should work:

```
content_type = ''
body = open("http://www.ruby-lang.org/en") {|f|
  content_type = f.content_type     # "text/html"
  f.read
}
```

I haven't tested that, but I think the return value of the block will be assigned to `body`. If that doesn't work then try:

```
content_type = ''
body = ''
open("http://www.ruby-lang.org/en") {|f|
  content_type = f.content_type     # "text/html"
  body = f.read
}
```

but I think the first will work.

Comment: You'd need to add some exception handling, and probably want to use the `Timeout` module to provide better control in case a request is taking too long. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964044/using-open-uri-to-fetch-xml-and-the-best-practice-in-case-of-problems-with-a-remo/4966240#4966240 for examples.

Comment: It seems to work all right with text based responses, though it does reformat them, but not image ones. I think I need to somehow stream the response to the Sinatra response...

Comment: There shouldn't be any reformatting as Open-URI is streaming the data without any transformation; It's basically a File I/O and is text/binary agnostic. I've retrieved MP3, PDF and images to disk in addition to retrieving lots of text using Open-URI. Sinatra might be doing something though. See my last comment for  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094304/how-to-access-a-web-page-from-sinatra/4094405#4094405 for streaming examples.

Comment: No problem. I was still editing. And, +1 for your question because it reminded me how way-cool Sinatra is. I haven't played with it for a while and I've missed it. Also check out Sinatra's big brother [Padrino](http://www.padrinorb.com/) which sits between Sinatra and Rails.

Comment: Cheers. It really is cool, I've only just started using it, and I'm amazed at it's power. I'll take a look at Padrino. Still having problems getting the new request response into the Sinatra one. But I'm a lot further along than I was 1 hour ago, thanks for the help.

Comment: I think I've got it (See my answer), though I still need to find a way to extract the contentType from the response, but for now this will do me.

Comment: @wm.wragg, You can get the content-type by passing a block to Open-URI's open statement instead of using the override on your uri to read. See the Open-URI docs linked in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of **the Tin Man** and **TK-421** I've worked out a solution, see the Sinatra route below:

```
get '/proxy/path' do
  require 'open-uri'
  uri = URI.parse(<URI>)
  getresult = uri.read
  halt 200, {'Content-Type' => getresult.content_type}, getresult
end
```

Just replace the `<URI>` with the page you require, and you're good to go.

After some more playing this is what I've come up with:

```
get '/proxy/path' do
   URI.parse(<URI> + request.query_string.gsub("|", "%7C")).read
end
```

As mentioned else where you need to `require 'open-uri'` at the top of the code. The reason for the `gsub` is that for some reason the parse fails if they are left in, and my browser doesn't encode them automatically.

Comment: the Tin Man provided the right answer. Good to see it's working. So, do you like Ruby better than C# yet? ;)

Comment: You can actually just use `return getresult` in place of `halt 200, {'Content-Type' => getresult.content_type}, getresult` as the uri returns a complete response, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I've never liked C#, only use it for work, I much prefer interpreted languages for my own coding (lisp, Scheme, Clojure, JavaScript). I'm quite new to Ruby, but really enjoying it :)

Comment: Don't `require` in the block... it's just wasteful. Not that it will load the lib every time, but it will check to see if it has loaded it.

Comment: "You can actually just use return getresult in place of halt 200, {'Content-Type' => getresult.content_type}, getresult as the uri returns a complete response" You don't need to use `return`. It's implied in Ruby, which returns the last value seen before exiting a block. You don't need to parse the URI either. `open` is happy with a string URL, so you're doing work that isn't needed and actually gets in the way of you being able to extract the `content_type` info you want.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot about Ruby implicitly returning the last expression, too much Java :) <br/> The reason I was using `URI.parse` rather than `open` was that when you `read` the parsed URI object it seems to return a complete response object, where as when you`read` the open object you get the body back only. It just seemed easier with the URI object. See update above.

Comment: This answer was still helpful a decade+ later!